# Spring JPA Can Modify Entity But Can't Create

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have this strange issue in my Spring JPA project that's preventing me from creating new users, but I can modify existing ones. I am implementing Spring JPA's  `CrudRepository` for my methods.

- There are 200 existing users in my table
- I can manually create with a SQL Script

If a User created through the form doesn't have an ID, I manually assign one to them - just for testing's sake

Class

```
@Entity(name="User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(){}
```

Form (Thymeleaf)

```
<form th:action="@{/saveUser}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
    <p>ID: <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
</form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", produces = "text/html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUser(
        @ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
        @RequestParam("id", required = false) Long Id, 
        Model model) {
    try {
        if(user.getId() == null || user.getId() == 0){
            user.setId(40000) //arbitrary ID
        }
        userRepo.save(user);
    } catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Error saving user" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return getUserForm(user.getId());   
}
```

However I get the error when saving

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'dbo.User'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails
```

I can see the user ID is indeed set when getting pushed to the save method  - is there anything I could be overlooking here?

Comment: where/how are you setting the `id` value in User?

Comment: Thymeleaf will bind the ID value with its th:field attribute if i am modifying an existing User record

Comment: Yes..Edit will work because the `Id` in the database will be mapped to the hidden field `<p>ID: <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" /></p>` and this `id` will be used for saving the user object. But for inserting a new `User`, you should specify the `Id` value by making the hidden filed to text field and give Id as an input or annotate the ` private Long id;` with `@Id @GeneratedValue` so that a primary key value will be generated autmatically and the object will be saved successfully.

Comment: I do have the @Id and @ GeneratedValue set now, and I need the ID input hidden so a user doesn't manually set it, the value will still send in the form. My issue here is that I am manually setting the ID right before the save method and its still being treated as if it were null when persisting. Does that make sense?

Comment: oops sorry I missed that part :) , Did you check whether the `if` condition is actually executing by printing something to the console?

Comment: Since the `id` type is Long...try using `user.setId(40000L)` to set the ID value

Comment: No mention of WHAT JPA implementation is being used (fairly important no?)

Comment: Post your user object, not only a snippet.

Comment: @BillyFrost you're right I've updated my the question - and @Omkar I believe L is only needed for primitive `long`

Comment: Whole object included

Comment: It looks like the column `Id` in the table `dbo.User` doesn't have generated values after all, or they are generated using a different strategy.

Comment: where is the JPA implementation specified? I don't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspicious two things in your code:

1. Take out the public constructor defining in the entity class. 
    (If I'm correct, JPA specification is not recommend it)
2. Take out "@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)" line from the entity class if that actually is not defined as in the table.

Good luck Clay!!!

Comment: Thanks Premium, the `@GeneratedValue` was the cause of the issue here, as I don't have an Identity set on the ID column within the User table

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a sequence that will be used like a strategy for automatically generating id values. This will save you from setting it manually.

Your model edited with what I meant above:

```
@Entity(name="User")
// Define a sequence
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
public class User {
    @Id
    // Attach the sequence
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    /** Getters & Setters **/
}
```